# Tilemap.SetTile only works with Vector3Int, but my tile size is in 0.16f increments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, tile

So in my Unity2D game, I need to change tiles inside a tilemap from within a script. I quickly found the Tilemap.SetTile function which asks for a Vector3Int position in his parameters, however my tile size is in 0.16f increments, which means that my tiles' Vector3 positions look like (0, -0.16f, 0).

```
public class BreakableWalls : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float tileSize = 0.16f;
    public int hp;
    public Tilemap tilemap;
    public TileBase fullTile;
    public TileBase brokenTile;

    public void Start()
    {
        for (float i = 0; i > -(tileSize * 3); i -= tileSize)
        {
            Vector3 currentTilePos = new Vector3(0, 0 - i, 0);
            TileBase tile = hp == 2 ? fullTile : brokenTile;
            tilemap.SetTile(currentTilePos, tile);
        }
    }
}
```

The principle is simple. I have breakable walls that can either start with 2 HP (need to be shot twice to be fully broken) or 1 HP (need to be shot once to be fully broken). A wall is composed of 3 tiles and I'm going through each tile (starting from the top one, as the top tile's position is always Vector3.zero) to update their appearance based on how much HP the wall has.

If my tileSize would be 1, this would work fine since SetTile needs a Vector3Int, but as of right now it won't work because of my 0.16f tileSize.

How can I work around this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tileSize` doesn't affect indexing by cell. Simply do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i > -3 ; i -= 1) 
{ 
    Vector3Int currentTileCellPos = new Vector3Int(0, i, 0); 
    TileBase tile = hp == 2 ? fullTile : brokenTile; 
    tilemap.SetTile(currentTileCellPos, tile); 
}
```

You don't actually seem to need the world position of the tile - you never use it in the question. And if you do, you can always do [`Vector3 currentTileWorldPos tilemap.CellToWorld(currentTileCellPos);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.CellToWorld.html)

Comment: Oh my lord, I didn't realize SetTile doesn't use the tile's position but rather their "tileMap" position (so, the tile under (0, 0, 0) is always (0, -1, 0)). That makes things much easier, thank you so much!